# How to mount windows shared folder with write access for apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

How can I mount a windows shared folder (windows allow write access) into my Ubuntu system, so that apache2 will be able to write there. Point is, I'm synchronizing folder files from my Windows PC, and Ubuntu machine acts only like the server, so problem is files created in shared folder at my Windows are not writable by apache (it can't open log files and other misc stuff)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I've found:

Find out the GID of the apache2, group default name is www-data, GID can and other user/group can be found at */System/Administration/Users* and Groups

Mount a folder using *smbfs* and pass the *dir_mode* and *file_mode* parameters together with the GID.

Best to store a command at your */etc/fstab* file, here is mine:

```
//192.168.72.2/Websites /home/brock/Windows smbfs iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,gid=33 0 0
```

Extra info can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Comment: this is pretty much the right way to do it.  the other option is to configure your Apache to run as another user that does have write access to the mount... but that is a bit more complicated and possibly less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the Windows Share as a Samba Share. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smbmount